# Difficulty evaluating complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The integral along the path $\gamma(t)=e^{2ti},\;t\in[0,2\pi]$  is
$\begin{equation*}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^{2}-1}dz
\end{equation*}$.

I approached this like a real integral in the hopes things would work out, first by performing a u sub
$\begin{equation*}
  u=e^{2ti}\Rightarrow du=2e^{2ti}dt\Rightarrow dt=\frac{du}{2e^{2ti}}
\end{equation*}$

Which brought me to 
$\begin{align*}
&\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\frac{i}{u^{2}-1}du=
i\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\frac{1}{(u+1)(u-1)}du\\
&=i\frac{1}{2}\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\frac{1}{(u+1)}du-
i\frac{1}{2}\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\frac{1}{(u-1)}du\end{align*}$

In the reals this would obviously $\frac{i}{2}\log(e^{2ti}-1)-\frac{i}{2}\log(e^{2ti}+1)|_{t=0}^{2\pi}$ but i am pretty sure this is wrong in the complex plane. I know there is a singularity at $z=e^{2ti}=\pm 1$, is this why I am ending up with problems? How should I evaluate integrals like this?

Comment: See residues theorem

Comment: how do i deal with the path hitting $-\pi i$ where log ceases to be unique?

Comment: wait sorry, I didn't see the huge problem : $\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ has a pole on the unit circle (two in fact) hence NO you can't integrate it on $|z| = 1$

Comment: try instead integrating $\frac{1}{z^2-1/2}$ on $|z|=1$, and think deep to the fact that when you'll write $\ln(e^{i t}-1/2)$ it is only a notation and is in fact a function of $t$ (not of $e^{it}$), continuous in $t \in \mathbb{R}$, hence $\ln(e^{2 i  \pi}-1/2) \ne \ln(1-1/2)$