# Complex integral evaluation; I get the right answer, but one of my steps is a little fishy

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-integration

The integral is $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^{2}-1}dz$ along the path $\gamma(t)=2e^{ti},\;t\in[0,2\pi]$
Which I attempt to do by parts:
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^{2}-1}dz=
    \frac{1}{2}[\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-1}dz-\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+1}dz]
  \end{equation*}
  And plugging in $z=\gamma(t)=2e^{it}$ gives
  \begin{align*}
    \frac{1}{2}[\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-1}dz-\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+1}dz]&=
    \frac{1}{2}[\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2e^{it}-1}dz-
    \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2e^{it}+1}dz]
  \end{align*}
  For which we perform the u subsitution
  \begin{equation*}
    u_{1}=2e^{ti}-1,\; u_{2}=2e^{ti}+1\Rightarrow dt=\frac{du_{1}}{2ie^{ti}}=
    \frac{du_{2}}{2ie^{ti}}
  \end{equation*}
  for both,
  yielding
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{1}{2}[\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\frac{1}{u}du-
    \int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}\frac{1}{u}du]=
    \frac{1}{2}\log(u)|_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\log(u)|_{t=0}^{t=2\pi}
  \end{equation*}
  And since $u_{1}(t=0)=1,\; u_{2}(t=2\pi)=2e^{2\pi i}-1=1$ and
  $u_{2}(t=0)=3,\; u_{2}(t=2\pi)=2e^{2\pi i}+1=3$ we have
  \begin{equation*}
    \frac{1}{2}\log(u)|_{1}^{1}-\frac{1}{2}\log(u)|_{3}^{3}=0
  \end{equation*}
  Also justifying ignoring the potential branch cut problems with log. 
My issue is that I assume that log will be well defined (i.e. its argument will be in the strip of the complex plane $(-\pi i,\pi i]$. Is this still ok?

Note: I asked about the same integral on a different path here: [Difficulty evaluating complex integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754907/difficulty-evaluating-complex-integral)
and made the judgement that this question because the path is different and I have a specific question about my computation. Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier to use the residue theorem to evaluate the integral.

Comment: I should have mentioned I do not have that available to me

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i 2 e^{it}}{2 e^{it}-1} dt = \ln(2e^{it}-1)|_{0}^{2\pi}$, the last formula being ONLY a notation : in fact $\ln(2e^{it}-1)$ should be read as "a function of $t$ such that its derivative is $\frac{2 i e^{it}}{2 e^{it}-1}$ for every $t \in [0,2\pi]$", that's how you get that this function doesn't have the same value at $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$. with this definition you also get that $\ln(2e^{it}-1)$ is continuous on $t \in [0,2\pi]$, and hence starting from $\ln(2 e^{0}-1) = 0$, we get $\ln(2 e^{2\pi}-1) = 2 i \pi$, and hence $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i 2 e^{it}}{2 e^{it}-1} dt=2i \pi$

Comment: and if $\gamma$ is $|z|=2$ traversed in counterclock-wise direction : $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-1} dz = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2 e^{it} -1} i 2 e^{it} dt$ with the parametrization $\gamma(t) = 2 e^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$ and the change of variable $ z = \gamma(t), dz = \gamma'(t) dt = 2 i e^{it} dt$